# Translation of multi-valued attributes

Tags: sql, database

If I have  a table customer with fields id, name, telephone.
A customer can have many telephone numbers.

this translation is right in sql?

table `customer: idcustomer pk,name`

what is the primary key of the phone?

which one is right? 
`phone: number pk, idcustomer pk,fk`

or  `phone: number, idcustomer fk, idphone pk`

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table customer: `idcustomer pk,name`

Table phone: `idphone pk, number, idcustomer fk`

Comment: Why? it's wrong?  phone: number pk, idcustomer pk,fk??

Comment: You can use phone number pk, but id is better, idCustomer is pk in table customer and fk in table table phone.